# Las Vegas Airport Navigation from Customs to Departures

Tags: usa, layovers, las-vegas, mexican-citizens

My brother is traveling from Mexico City to Salt Lake City but he has a layover in Las Vegas. He does not speak English and I was wondering if there is an easy way to get him from customs in Las Vegas back in departures for his next flight. His arrival flight is trough Volaris and next flight is with Frontier

Comment: I am assuming he does speak Spanish.

Comment: Further to @Karlson's comments, I suspect very strongly that there are Spanish-speaking staff and CBP officers working in the Las Vegas airport.

Comment: There are VIP services that will meet a passenger at the deplaning site and escort them through immigration and on to their departure gate.

Comment: Simply tell your brother to notify the Volaris flight crew that he will be needing help with his transfer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Once he exits Customs, he'll simply need to take an elevator upstairs to Level 2 and either recheck his bags at Frontier's ticketing counter, or proceed directly to the security checkpoint if he has no bags to check. All of these steps will occur within Terminal 3.

Once he has passed through the security checkpoint, straight ahead he'll see some escalators that lead to the D Concourse. He'll go downstairs via escalator (or elevator if he prefers) and then he'll see a tram station just ahead. He can board the next tram to the D Concourse, and from there he'll just need to find his gate upstairs.

There are signs to lead the way, and we have staff who can offer assistance in Spanish if needed. It's not a difficult connection.

- Chris Jones with McCarran International Airport

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for joining and helping with this answer.

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE Chris!